# JavaFX RCP detach Part

Tags: java, javafx, eclipse-rcp, add-on, efxclipse

I'm studying javaFX and I want to create a plug-in project (RCP) based on java FX.

Then, I created an fxml of test and linked to the Application.e4xmi, which structure is shown in the following figure.

[image]

Therefore, I tested that it cannot be possible to shift a Part from/to a stack.

On the web I saw that, to do it, I have to insert an Add-on inside the project. in details which name is  **DnDAddon**.

Then, now the bigger problem: I'm not be able to detach the Part outside the application/workbanch.

I know from https://github.com/eclipse-efx/efxclipse-rt/issues/256  and from https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1083410/ that it was a problem, but now is there a solution??

Thank!!

Answer (score 0):

Resolved :P !

I post the solution because it can be useful to someone.

In the `Windoiw preferences`-> `Plug_in Development` -> `Target Platform`

Then, here you have to add as Software the nightly version: http://download.eclipse.org/efxclipse/runtime-nightly/site

Therefore, to enable the Part detach feature, you have to insert inside the `Run Configurations`->Arguments->VM Arguments:

-Ddetachdrag.enabled=true

Regards.